# How to write SharePoint List Web Service (Sharepoint 2007)

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am begginer and never written any web service.
We are using sharepoint 2007 and we want to access and display SharePoint List from one site to another site,but both sharepoint sites are on different server.
For this Please let me know how to write and access Web Service for same.
Please share if an imp link or reference.

Thanks in advance,
Rushikesh

Comment: Madhur is right on this one with the two links he's given you. The question is how you want to access the Lists Web Service: in managed code, client side script, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by different server ? Do you mean different SharePoint farms ?

If the both are in same Active Directory domain, you can simply access the OOTB web services to display the data. Use the Lists Web Service:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists(v=office.12).aspx

You can also use SPServices library for the same. See:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2010/04/12/using-jquery-and-spservices-to-display-list-items.aspx

Comment: yes on different sharepoint farms.
We have two windows servers and on both server sharepoint is installed.
We want to access list in between those two servers site.